# Error deploying shinyapp fatal error: plogr.h: No such file or directory

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to deploy a Shiny app. When the app is running in RStudio I select the deploy button to republish my updated app.

After a minute or so I receive the following error block in the console:

```
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/dplyr/include/dplyr/main.h:11:19: fatal error: plogr.h: No such file or directory
 #include <plogr.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/dplyr/include/dplyr.h:4:0,
                 from rows-data.cpp:2:
/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/dplyr/include/dplyr/main.h:11:19: fatal error: plogr.h: No such file or directory
 #include <plogr.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [rows.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [rows-data.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘purrr’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/purrr’
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 492377328 failed: Error building image: Error building purrr (0.2.2). Build exited with non-zero status: 1
Execution halted
```

I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/71yNwL8zdCs) discussion on Google groups. Reading through this discussion I tried to reinstall dplyr with dependencies = T.

Here are the libraries I try to load with my app:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(lubridate)
library(DT)
library(scales)
```

I also tried to install plogr directly:

```
> install.packages("plogr.h")
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘plogr.h’ is not available (for R version 3.3.3)
```

Does anyone have any advice for deploying my Shinyapp based on this info? What should I do to get around this error?

Comment: You can always install packages form file, just [download](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plogr/index.html) file and install it in rstudio. packages -> install -> install from -> package archive file (.zip; .tar.gz) then it should work

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Should I try to install plogr.h? is that what you are suggesting? So download into the same directory as the shiny app?

Comment: I had the same problem with some packages from bioconductor. Download it whatever you want, and install from file using rstudio, than `library(plogr.h)` should work and it fact your whole app. [Here](https://impaulchung.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/packageinstall.png?w=625&h=431) change from CRAN to .zip; .tar.gz and find downloaded file

Comment: OK added plogr via download. Is the idea that I upload the file to shinyapps too? Or once it's installed I can just deploy as usual?

Comment: I downloaded plogr then installed via file. Then I tried to deploy to Shinyapps and got the exact same error message again

Comment: Not sure if plogr.h is a distinct library from plogr but I cannot find plogr.h anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Doug Fir I also struggled with this but finally got this working.

1) I first also tried with no luck to

```
install.packages("dplyr", dependencies = TRUE)
```

2) So I then took a good look at the error messages on Deploy tab in Rstudio and noticed that it was **complaining about another package or two**. In this case `purrr` and `Rcpp`. So I reinstalled these two as well.

so I:

```
install.packages(c("Rcpp","purrr"))
```

3) I noticed **Shiny was not up to date** (1.0.1 not 1.0.5) so I updated that for good measure.

```
install.packages("shiny")
```

4) then **quit Rstudio** and restarted R.

Shiny app with dplyr then finally redeployed. Not sure if this beats your answer, but at least `dplyr 0.7.4` worked without needing to downgrade.

*I am posting this to provide clues if someone else has this problem.*

Comment: Thanks for contributing, your answer is more concise than my own and I'll try these steps after updating to newer version of dplyr again.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded an earlier version of DPLYR (0.5.0 no reason, just randomly chose that version) from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/). Doing this seemed to fix everything, I don't know why.